# plot wide range of data with PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

I want to use PSTricks in order to plot data in a file. In general I know how to do it but the problem now is that these data run from x=-2000...2000 and y=1.e-10...1e-3 so I get the "too large" error. When I try to change the data or the axis, I have a new problem: I can't get the right ticks. 
Does any body have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you provide your non-working but **minimal** code ans some dummy data?

Comment: Also you should go over your old questions and check whether you consider them answered. If you do, you should mark them as such by clicking the tick mark next to the best answer.  If you haven't received the answers you were looking for, you should edit your questions to include more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can scale points different to the coordinates values:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\def\demoValues{-2000 1.e-10 -1000 1.e-5 0 0 1000 1.e-4 2000 1.e-3}
\begin{psgraph}[arrows=->,ticksize=0 5pt,
  Dy=0.2,
  xlabelFactor=\cdot10^3,
  ylabelFactor=\cdot10^{-3},
  ](0,0)(-2.2,-0.1)(2.2,1.1){7cm}{7cm}
  \pstScalePoints(1,1){1000 div}{1.e3 mul}
  \listplot[plotstyle=dots,dotstyle=x,dotscale=2,linecolor=red]
  {\demoValues}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using a log axis for y may make sense here.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to change label "x" and "y" with psgraph?

Comment: sure, for example: `\psset{xAxisLabel=x-Value,xAxisLabelPos={c,-0.2}}` write it before `psgraph`. Same is possible for the y axis.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `pgfplots`, there's no need to scale the data manually, it handles the scaling automatically:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table {
-2000 1e-10
-1000 1e-5
0 0
1000 1e-4
2000 1e-3
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```